# Laying out divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Basic structure as of now: http://jsfiddle.net/sv_in/wbhr8/

The final structure that I want is like below (doctored image):

[image: layout I want]

- I **have** to support IE7+ so if it can be achieved at least with polyfills also, I am happy.
- I am not interested in solutions positioning them in **absolute position**
- I am not interested in solutions using major **DOM manipulation** as the order of the 'li's is important for my need.

Couldn't solve the riddle myself so are there any experts out there???

PS: Even if this is impossible, do give your reasons for me to learn.

**UPDATE:**

- I cannot use a table or multiple ULs like http://jsfiddle.net/wbhr8/31/ coz there would a lot of 'li's like this (20+) and I may need to remove the first one or two and still this layout should be maintained.
- The number of items would be dynamic so.... would like this layout to work for them all.

Comment: Is it necessary to have one ul with li?? can be easily done using to ul

Comment: u mean multiple uls? I would prefer a single UL as the order of the LIs are important for me :(

Comment: yes, still you can have li in it

Comment: I am saying something like this **http://jsfiddle.net/wbhr8/26/**

Comment: Would you want this to continue for 4, 5, 6 ... ?

Comment: I would really want an answer to this one, because it's very interesting `css` styling! :)

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that it's impossible without resorting to some positioning tomfoolery, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wbhr8/95/

```
<ul class="container">
   <li class="box">1</li>
   <li class="box even">2</li>
   <li class="box">3</li>
   <li class="box even">4</li>
   <li class="box">5</li>
   <li class="box even">6</li>
</ul>

.container {
   height: 205px;
   width: 1000px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.box {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color:yellow;
   border: 1px solid red;
   color: black;
   float:left;
}

.even{
   position: relative;
   top: 102px;
   margin-left: -102px;
}
```

And the reason is it's just not in the tool kit at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wbhr8/3/

There you go :)

Comment: A bit of an explanation would be of value to readers, rather than just a link which may disappear at any time.

Comment: That is sort of absolute positioning (`margin-top:102px;`)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty yes, but every solution will be hackish.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wbhr8/29/)**.

HTML unmodifed. CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 205px;
    width: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: black;
    display:inline-block;
}

​.box1,.box2 {
    float:left;
}
.box2 {
    clear:left;
}
​
```

I set the `.box` elements to have an inline-block display then floated the first two while also clearing the second. Note that I only have IE8 running in IE7 mode to test with and not the actual IE7.

Comment: Really good but how can I make this layout work for dynamic number of items?

Comment: @sv_in - a dynamic number of lists (`<ul>`) or list items (`<li>`)?

Comment: @sv_in - so if you have more list items, what would the resulting layout look like? Are all but the last list item expected to flow down the left side with the last list item next to the first?

Comment: @sv_in - do the list items always have the same class structure (box and boxX) or can that be changed?

Comment: @j08691 : I only added the classes for my reference. You can change them as you want